# "every regular functions is differentiable infinitely"

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Is there a theorem that states something like "every regular functions is differentiable infinitely"?

I want to prove that 
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
(or similar "simple" functions) has a second derivative without actually calculating it.

Comment: What is a regular function?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I can't define that. I mean a function consisting of regular operations etc. Analytic maybe? I'm thinking of a specific theorem which I know exists

Comment: @IdiotWithNoShame If you can't define it, then how can you expect to work with it?

Comment: By the way, what you say you want to do: show that a function has a second derivative without actually calculating it is possible only in complex analysis. In that place, differentiability is a much more stringent condition than in the real line. Indeed, it is usually shown in a first course in complex variables that any complex differentiable function *automatically* has a second derivative. I know you already know the implications of this, hence your title.

Comment: He means elementary functions without square roots or absolute values, defined on the greatest interval possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "regular" may mean different things in different mathematical contexts. There is the notion of [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). These are functions defined by explicit expressions in a variable $x$, whereby these expressions are built up according to reasonable rules, involving functions like $\exp$, $\cos$, $\log$, $\sqrt{\cdot}$, etcetera, and have domains $\subset{\mathbb R}$, or ${\mathbb C}$. It is easy to check that the derivative of an elementary function is again elementary (maybe on a smaller domain); hence the elementary functions are "formally" infinitely differentiable.

But note that we have spoken here only about functions defined by "analytical expressions". If you are thinking about "abstract" functions $f:\>{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ you cannot expect differentiability, let alone $C^\infty$, i.e., infinite differentiability.